How to SUM only the five largest value out of nine Textbox?
I need to sum only the five largest number out of  Nine Textbox value
TextBox11 = WorksheetFunction.Sum(Large((Val(TextBox2.Text) + Val(TextBox3.Text) + Val(TextBox4.Text) + Val(TextBox5.Text) + Val(TextBox6.Text) + Val(TextBox7.Text) + _
Val(TextBox8.Text) + Val(TextBox9.Text) + Val(TextBox10.Text)), " 1, 2, 3, 4, 5"))

sum only five large numbers out of nine numbers

What have you tried? You could put the values into an array, sort the array and sum the first five elements of the array. If the VBA host is excel you only need to call WorksheetFunction.sort for the sorting.

Sum Up Top Values

You can utilize your idea by putting the values in an array suggested by Storax in your comments.
The result in the message box is 35 (9+8+7+6+5).

Sub SumUpTopValues()
    
    Const TOP_VALUES As Long = 5

    ' Simple Test
    
    Dim Values() As Variant: Values = Array(3, 2, 1, 5, 7, 6, 4, 8, 9)
    
    With Application
        MsgBox .Sum(.Large(Values, _
            Application.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & TOP_VALUES & ")")))
    End With
    
    ' For Real

'    Dim Values() As Variant: Values = Array( _
'        Val(TextBox2.Text), Val(TextBox3.Text), Val(TextBox4.Text), _
'        Val(TextBox5.Text), Val(TextBox6.Text), Val(TextBox7.Text), _
'        Val(TextBox8.Text) + Val(TextBox9.Text) + Val(TextBox10.Text))
'
'    With Application
'        TextBox11.Text = .Sum(.Large(Values, _
'            Application.Evaluate("ROW(1:" & TOP_VALUES & ")")))
'    End With

End Sub

